# Does the 0x00 address has some amount of any ERC20 token? Want to simulate

Tags: transactions, erc-20, simulation

I want to be able to generate txid simulations on a forked blockchain programmatically, with the only details being known to the program are the functions to be executed.

This will be used for fetching details about a staking/lending contract automatically, but there is one problem - To simulate without knowing the token that will be deposited into a contract, i would need to at least know of an address that holds that token (and therefore would be able to deposit in the simulation when i mimic it)

Now i heard somewhere that the "0x000...000" void address 'always' has some amount of an erc20 token - is that true? Would definitely make it much easier if it does... But it sounds untrue

Answer (score 0):

It depend which Blockchain you are forking.

But yes, any major blockchain networks, likes of ETH, Avalanche, Matic, and ERC20 projects developed on them, will often have some token balance on 0x000...000 because that address is used for burning tokens (Basically, you destroy tokens by sending them there)

Comment: Yea so i know the 0x00 is often used as a burn address, but my question is - Is that something consistent?

I am assuming if a certain token has never intentionally burned any tokens then it wouldn't work - In which case it would be very inconsistent

Comment: Yes, if nothing vas ever burned, that address would be empty.